Confused about symmetric game theory utility
I imagine this is a stupid question and I'm missing something obvious, but I can't really make heads or tails of this and seem to be unable to find good resources online, so here goes.
I'm working through Algorithmic Game Theory and am looking at Example 2.2:
Example 2.2
I track the calculated utilities for player 1, assuming player 2 runs the strategy (0, 1/3, 2/3). I understand the point here that player 2's best option in this case is to play a mix of strategies 2 and 3. However, I don't understand the utilities from player 2's perspective.
Assuming player 1 plays (0, 1/3, 2/3), for player 2 strategy 1 should yield 2 * 2/3 = 4/3. Strategy 2 should yield 2 * 2/3 = 4/3. Strategy 3 should yield 3 * 1/3 + 2 * 2/3 = 7/3.
In the example it says "while the entries are the utilities of Player 1, the opposite holds for matrix B", so I assume this means that player 2 is attempting to minimize the utility. However, if that's true, 2 should run some mix of strategies 1 and 2, and shouldn't touch strategy 3. If, on the contrary, Player 2 is trying to maximize the utility, he should run strategy 3 exclusively. I don't see how, in any case, (0, 1/3, 2/3) is the strategy vector player 2 should employ, though it does make sense for Player 1. So I don't see how this is a Nash equilibrium.
Again I imagine I'm missing something obvious or perhaps something just wasn't explained well enough and this is easy to clarify. I'd appreciate any help.

(1) There are different reasons why links to pictures aren’t great. (2) Please use MathJax whenever you type a formula on this site. It’s pretty easy. You just enclose your formulae into the $ signs, for the most part. And use \times or \cdot instead of * for multiplication.

Player 2's payoff matrix is $A^T$ and you forgot to transpose, so the payoff from strategy 2 is $\frac23\cdot3=2$ and the payoff from strategy 3 is $\frac13\cdot 2 +  \frac23 \cdot 2=2$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
